# POST vs post, GET vs get

Tags: html, forms, tags, capslock

I realize that both will work, but is one more correct than the other?

```
<form method="POST" />
```

vs.

```
<form method="post" />
```

Why use one or the other?

Comment: W3C calls these 'enumerated attributes' and recommends lowercase for both name and value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45834938/498634 is a more recent answer with references to today's standards.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

W3C has tended towards lowercase for attribute names and values for a while.

For example section 4.11 of the [xhtml 1.0 standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/) in 2002:

> > 4.11. Attributes with pre-defined value sets
> >
> > HTML 4 and XHTML both have some
> >     attributes that have pre-defined and
> >     limited sets of values (e.g. the type
> >     attribute of the input element). In
> >     SGML and XML, these are called
> >     enumerated attributes. Under HTML 4,
> >     the interpretation of these values was
> >     case-insensitive, so a value of TEXT
> >     was equivalent to a value of text.
> >     Under XML, the interpretation of these
> >     values is case-sensitive, and in XHTML
> >     1 all of these values are defined in
> >     lower-case.

Answer (score 14):

[You can use either of them](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#case-insensitive) why because HTML is not case-sensitive markup language.

[See HTML 4.01 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-method)

> The value is case-insensitive (i.e., user agents 
>    interpret "a" and "A" as the same).

---

Note that [XHTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/) should be lower case.

> 4.2. Element and attribute names must be in lower case
>
> XHTML documents must use lower case
>   for all HTML element and attribute
>   names. This difference is necessary
>   because XML is case-sensitive e.g.
>   `<li>` and `<LI>` are different tags.

Comment: It's worth noting that XHTML (note the X) *is* case-sensitive - tags and attribute names should all be lower-case. That said, I'm not aware of case-restrictions on well-defined attribute *values*.

Comment: Is this not down to the doctype? because XML requires lower-case.

Comment: @RobM: It is good that you mentioned XHTML standard, though here I meant HTML 4.01 specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-method. Update the answer though :)

Comment: @Sarfraz regarding you XHTML edit. That quotation states that attribute names should be in lower-case, not attribute values.

Comment: @Alin Purcaru: Attribute values should also be lower case if you could browser through the docs :) `Under HTML 4, the interpretation of these values was case-insensitive, so a value of TEXT was equivalent to a value of text. Under XML, the interpretation of these values is case-sensitive, and in XHTML 1 all of these values are defined in lower-case.`

Comment: @Sarfraz See amelvin's answer. Attribute values (not names!) should be in lowercase only for predefined values. You can't say that having `id="MYID"` is not valid XHTML.

Comment: @Alin Purcaru: I think it says the same thing, in xhtml, attribute values should be lower case ;)

Comment: No they shouldn't. Pay attention. I even gave you an example. You have to make a distinction between attribute names and attribute values. `name="value"`.

Comment: `<img src="avatar.png" alt="Comment by David Dorward">` — I'd rather not see proper nouns made lower case! The words **these values** are important, it limits the rule to *enumerated attributes* (as opposed to all attributes).

Answer (score 8):

[Either way is fine](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html) for HTML. There is not specific recommendation.

> Possible (case-insensitive) values are
>   "get" (the default) and "post".

There are arguments for both uppercase and lowercase. One could say that the default for HTML (and mandatory for XHTML) tokens is to write them in lowercase, but saying that the values used in HTTP requests are the uppercase ones is equally valid.

Answer (score 4):

Either is fine. It's not case sensitive. w3schools implies the w3c recommends lower case for HTML: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp

Here is the w3c XHTML lower-case requirement for attributes: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.2

Comment: w3schools in in no way affiliated with w3c!

Comment: Eugh. I wish W3Schools had bothered to link to that recommendation, because I can't find it anywhere. In general, avoid W3Schools. They are highly error prone.

Comment: @Alin — I'd normally be shouting that myself, but the cited page states that the W3C makes that recommendation (although it doesn't say where they do). The answer could be better worded to avoid the implication though.

Comment: Well, as you can see from the links posted in my answer and that of others, w3c says both are equally fine and if you take a look through the chapter about forms you will see both forms used.

Comment: No, the link you posted shows that W3Schools claims that the W3C says they are both equally find. Since W3Schools are untrustworthy, that isn't very helpful.

Comment: But don't forget that real request should be sent with POST or GET method name, it is case sensitive. Proxies may not allow low case methods names.

Answer (score 2):

As with most coding conventions, consistency is key.  Pick the casing you are most comfortable with and make sure to use it throughout your code.

Comment: WhAt If I DoNe My MaRkUp LiKe ThIs, I Choose 'Mixed Case' :)

Comment: @RoBeRtPiTt: ThEn YoU BeTtEr KeEp DoInG iT lIkE tHaT!

Answer (score 2):

From the [HTML 4.01 Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-method):

> This attribute specifies which HTTP method will be used to submit the form data set. Possible **(case-insensitive)** values are "get" (the default) and "post".

**XHTML** is different, and the attribute values there **are** case sensitive and must be **lower case**.

> Under HTML 4, the interpretation of these values was case-insensitive, so a value of TEXT was equivalent to a value of text. Under XML, the interpretation of these values is case-sensitive, and in XHTML 1 all of these values are defined in lower-case.

The above is from [XHTML 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.11) (Hat tip to @amelvin for spotting something I assumed was another case of an undocumented change).

Comment: Thanks for the hat tip - knowing these attribute values can be called 'enumerated attributes' was interesting (if retrospectively obvious).