# Should I use method="POST" or "post" in HTML form?

Tags: php, html, forms, http-post

I want to handle data with PHP by post method and I want to know if both ways ("post" and "POST") are recommended.

Should I use `method="POST"` or `method="post"` in HTML form?

Thanks.

Comment: HTML attribute names and attribute values are case-insensitive, if that's your question.

Comment: @lafor Not if a form contains `name="Email"` as opposed to `name="email"`

Comment: Capitalization of some things matters, due to the XHTML standard. See my answer.

Comment: I don't think it really matters on how it's spelled, as long as it's `Post` `POST` or `post`

Comment: they are case-incensitive, most programmers use captial case for the methods and as long as you remain consistent you should be fine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45834938/498634 is a more recent answer with references to today's standards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better to stick with lowercase so you aren't tempted to type all your tags and attributes as if you're shouting at the browser. Also, you should be coding your modern HTML to the XHTML standard, not to 90s HTML.

This is the 90s way: `<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="">`

Today its advised to use lowercase for tags and attributes, although for the values of the attributes do whatever you want:  `<form method="post" action="">`,  `<form method="POST" action="">`

Why?  Because of XHTML.  For a document to be valid XHTML the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.2) says:

> 4.2. Element and attribute names must be in lower case
>
> XHTML documents must use lower case for all HTML element and attribute names. This 
>   difference is necessary because XML is case-sensitive e.g. `<li>` and `<LI>` are 
>   different tags.

Of course for ids and names like in `<input id='x' name='product_id' />` the capitalization matters as `<input id='X' name='Product_Id' />` the id is different to the DOM and the name sent to the server is now different.

Comment: XHTML has lost its relevancy. Since HTML5 the normalized serialization is sufficient. Unless you actually utilize different XMLNSes, synthetic attribute quotes and strict casing are causeless bells and whistles.

Comment: @mario, Until you want to parse your HTML with an XML parser to make some changes to it programmatically or extract some things. I prefer not having to go back and clean that up first.

Comment: I'd rather use a HTML parser frontend than a XML one on HTML.

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt matter, HTML isnt case sensitive though its more common to capitalize it.

Comment: *"HTML isnt case sensitive"* --- No, and yes. Just not in this case, but variables are, as are PHP variables. `$var` and `$Var` are two different animals altogether. OP might get the wrong impression.

Comment: Yes PHP indeed case sensitive.

Comment: That's `not` my -1 btw.

Comment: Thats cool, i have no hard feelings lol

Comment: You're a real sport ;-)