# Why does Django use uppercase & W3C tends towards lowercase names for HTTP request methods

Tags: django, http, http-post, httprequest, w3c

This [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4106613/781695) says:
 `W3C has tended towards lowercase for attribute names and values for a while` i.e. use something like

```
<form method="post" />
```

However, in a Django view, the method name is [compared with an uppercase string](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view)

```
if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
```

Why are the cases mixed up here ? Is the browser converting 'post' to uppercase for Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP method names are case-sensitive, and all registered method names are all-uppercase.

The lowercase spelling in HTML form attributes essentially is a bug in HTML that is impossible to fix due to backwards compatibility reasons.

Comment: Is it acknowledged as a `bug` officially?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is part of the reason : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10766285/781695. Though it doesn't answer the discrepancy between W3C & RFC 3875

[RFC 3875](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3875) defines the `REQUEST_METHOD` variable as upper case, so it's okay to rely on it.

> The REQUEST_METHOD meta-variable MUST be set to the method which
>      should be used by the script to process the request ...
>
> ```
>   REQUEST_METHOD   = method
>   method           = "GET" | "POST" | "HEAD" | extension-method
>   extension-method = "PUT" | "DELETE" | token
> ```
>
> The method is case sensitive.